# What is the correct way to bring data from the controller to the vue.js? Laravel-vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I haven't really used this method before and I'm confused where I'm going wrong.

I set the data in the controller, I added the mycourses entry but it's not coming through, everything else is coming in fine

```
$data['user'] = Auth::user()->load('userType');
$data['courses'] = StudentSchedule::where('instructor_id',Auth::user()->id)
    ->with('course', 'package.packageCourses', 'user', 'location')->get();
$data['mycourses'] = Course::all();
$data['locations'] = Location::all();

return view('home', $data);
```

After this I go to the blade and add this

```
<script>
    const user = {!! json_encode($user) !!};
    const mycourses = {!! json_encode($mycourses) !!};
    const courses = {!! json_encode($courses) !!};
    const locations = {!! json_encode($locations) !!};
</script>
```

Then this goes to the .js, but whats happening there is that its calling the vue

In the vue file I add this to the data()

```
courses: [],
mycourses: [],
locations: [],
```

In the vue file I add this to the mounted

```
this.courses = courses;
this.mycourses = mycourses;
this.locations = locations;
```

And the mycourses is giving me this error

> Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: mycourses is not defined"
>
> ReferenceError: mycourses is not defined

I added mycourses after all the other ones were added before, I have everything the same as the courses one and I'm still getting this error. What am I missing?

Comment: your only returning $data, your not returning $mycourses.
have you tried something like const mycourses = {!! json_encode($data['mycourses']) !!}; ?

Comment: Are you passing the data array to a vue component? Do you have the option to pass as props?

Comment: @hurnhu that doesn't work

Comment: @Damon I'm not sure, I've never done it that way, and the weird part is the other stuff is all working doing it that way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be helpful or not, meaning perhaps there is a reason this method won't work given your circumstances.

I've found this method of setting/passing data to be pretty helpful. It's less overhead to have to parse in your blade templates (or wherever needed).

**Controller**

```
public function myFunction() {
    ...

    $user = Auth::user()->load('userType');
    $courses = StudentSchedule::where('instructor_id', $user->id)->with('course', 'package.packageCourses', 'user', 'location')->get();
    $mycourses = Course::all();
    $locations = Location::all();

    // Verify the data is correct.
    // dd($courses);

    return view('example', compact('user', 'courses', 'mycourses', 'locations');
}
```

You can verify each is returning the value needed by checking what it's returning using `dd()`.

If you have a vue component you are passing data to that exists in your blade template, you could do something like this to [pass the data in as props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

**example.blade.php**

```
<p>Example content...</p>
<p>Hello, {{ $user->name }}</p>
<example-component :courses="courses" :mycourses="mycourses"></example-component>
<p>...</p>
```

Now we have passed `courses` and `mycourses` to the view component. You can access them there:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ExampleComponet',
        data() {
            return {
                //
            }
        },
        methods: {
            //
        },
        props: {
            courses: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
            mycourses: {
                type: Object, 
                required: true
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

You'll need to update the property *type* for each of the props you pass in. Perhaps `courses` isn't an object, but rather a string.

I'm not sure if I've exactly *solved* your issue, but hope this helps get you in the right direction.